# Java 8 - Get content of predicate (Reflection API?)

Tags: java, reflection, predicate

I use a **custom** access layer (not relational, not standardized in any way) which is in the form of a jar file, like an API. This access layer provides a custom way to filter the results when I ask a
"query". I wrap this custom data access layer using the Repository design pattern, following a design similar to the one described [here](http://www.lestard.eu/2015/generic_repository_part1/), in order to hide its complexity to the above layers.

Therefore, one of my repository's functions to execute queries would be something like the one following:

```
public class Repository { 
    
    // Other methods...

    public Set<CustomEntity> get(Predicate<CustomEntity> predicate) {
        // code using the predicate in order to create a custom filter string
        String filterExpression = ...;
        
        Set<CustomEntity> queryResults = CustomDataAccessLayer.query(filterExpression);

        return queryResults;
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```

A typical call of the above method would be something like

```
Set<CustomEntity> queryResults = customEntitiesRepository.get(
    p -> p.property1 == "criterio 1" && p.property2 == "criterio 2"
);
```

Obviously, the method `get` would translate the `predicate` with two criteria in the custom access layer's filtering mechanism. However, I don't know how to retrieve the content of the `predicate` in order to apply the filters to the custom access layer. Is there such a mechanism? Is it feasible to use reflection API or something like that in order to retrieve a predicate's conditions?

**Edit**: I could retrieve all the entities from the custom access layer API and then check if they validate the predicate criteria through the `Predicate.test`
method. However, this would require retrieving **all data**
from the custom access layer in prior (eager loading), which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I am trying to convert the predicate into a custom access layer filter string (namely the string variable `filterExpression`) in order to build a **"lazy loading"** repository.

Comment: I don't understand. You have a `Predicate`. Just use it to `test` a `CustomEntity` value.

Comment: Are you looking for `Predicate#test`? It's in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

Comment: please give a concrete example showing what you can't achieve because so far it is not clear at all

Comment: The condition is compiled Java byte code. That is, it looks for values in certain offsets in the parameter object, performs comparisons and sets a register to the result. I think a better approach would be to convert whatever you have in your repository into a `CustomEntity` and then call the predicate's `test` on it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I have just edited my question. I hope it is a little bit clearer now.

Comment: Honestly you really shouldn't be using `Predicate`s like this at all. Use your own custom query string builder, or something akin to Hibernate's Criteria API.

Comment: @kaqqao Thank you for your comment, I would however disagree. The custom access layer is not a relational database and therefore I could not bind a hibernate on it. What I am trying to achieve here is to provide a **strongly typed** repository, wrapping this custom access layer. I am not really familiar with Hibernate's  Criteria API, however judging from [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) it does not seem like a strongly typed API. If I have to choose a not strongly typed solution, I would go with a simpler one, just using a filter strings.

Comment: I didn't say you should use Hibernate, just build something similar to its API. But I've just realized Criteria API is a JPA standard, not Hibernate specific, and it was built exactly to be a type safe way to issue queries.

Comment: @kaqqao Once again thank you very much for your time. I really appreciate it. When I say that Criteria API is not strongly typed, is because in a statement Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") the parameter name is a string. If they have used predicates, the name would be an entity field. Of course, you are right saying that Criteria API provides strongly typed access for parts of the process (e.g. defining that something is a restriction, or the kind of restriction) but it does not allow strongly typing the respective fields per se, while a predicate would.

Comment: Don't know that much about the Criteria API, but I see a lot of examples like: `cq.where(pet.get(Pet_.color).isNull());` where field names are not strings. Check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: @kaqqao Thank you very much for the example. You reference seems to be a good start.